# MVC user gets logged out after modifying database manually or modifying resx file programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, resx

I have an application written in C#, MVC, using Entity Framework and CodeFirst approach. I have a problem with users being logged out after modifying database manually. While this is not a big problem because such thing won't be happening a lot when the service is done, the problem is more irritating when logged in administrator changes the .resx file containing translations. We created an administartor panel where one can add languages, change default texts displayed on the site and so on. Everytime I change a text (so a row in .resx file) I get logged out. I don't know where the problem is and how to trace it. Dunno if it will help but here is the code for editing existing texts in .resx file:

```
using (ResXResourceReader resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(resxFilePath))
{
    resx = resxReader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();
    var existingResource = resx.SingleOrDefault(entry => entry.Key.ToString().Equals(model.EntryName));
    var modifiedResx = new DictionaryEntry()
    {
        Key = existingResource.Key,
        Value = model.NewEntryValue
    };

    resx.Remove(existingResource);
    resx.Add(modifiedResx);
 }

 using (ResXResourceWriter resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(resxFilePath))
 {
     resx.ForEach(r =>
     {
         resxWriter.AddResource(r.Key.ToString(), r.Value.ToString());
                });
         resxWriter.Generate();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change Resources (.resx) at runtime.
You can only get a `Resource`value by writing this piece of code.

```
 ProjectTest.Resources.Message
```

You can use [Application settings and User setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx) for this purpose.

This will allow you to use the designer to build the settings, and write:

```
string string1 = Properties.Settings.Default.String1;
```

And:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.String1 = "whatever";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: But I don't get it how do I put different languages there? Every single text has to have the same exact name so it can be displayed on pages using it. Trying to understand your approach, text 'Hello World' would have to be kept in n rows, where n is the number of langauges, right?